# mule's http-proxy cannot be used in flow?

Tags: mule

I would like to do a proxy for backend rest service, but before I forward the request to backend, I need to do some checks. I checked the docments, there is a http-proxy can be used to do the proxy, but when I put into the flow, there are exceptions. If I use the  http:outbound-endpoint the method cannot be a dynamic MEL expression(rest method could be POST, GET, PUT, DELTE etc).

Could you give me a suggestion? An example will be better, Thanks a lot.
My Configuration:

```
<flow name="demo.routerFlow1" doc:name="demo.routerFlow1">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP" />
  <logger
    message="Method: #[message.inboundProperties['http.method']], URI: #[message.inboundProperties['http.request.path']], Params: #[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']]"
    level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map" />
  <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="(payload['timestamp'] == null || payload['nonce'] == null)">
      <expression-component doc:name="Check Required Params"><![CDATA[payload="{\"code\":\"PA001\", \"message\":\"missing required parameter timestamp and nonce\"}"]]>
      </expression-component>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="!replayAttackCheck.validate(payload)" evaluator="groovy">
          <expression-component doc:name="Check Required Params"><![CDATA[payload="{\"code\":\"PA002\", \"message\":\"timestamp or nonce is illegal\"}"]]>
          </expression-component>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
          <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <pattern:http-proxy name="http-proxy-sample"> <!--line 38-->
              <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/"></http:inbound-endpoint>
              <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/"></http:outbound-endpoint>
            </pattern:http-proxy>
          </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
      </choice>
    </otherwise>
  </choice>
</flow>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'processor-chain' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration patterns are standalone and separate from any flow and cannot be configured within one. They are predefined integration patterns for common scenarios. Flows are for rolling your own. See here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Choosing+Between+Flows+and+Patterns

As a side note: Your already listening on localhost:8080, so I think you just want a http:outbound-endpoint to the service your running on 8081

```
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/" />
```

Comment: but I cannot set a dynamic method, like: <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:7081#[message.inboundProperties['http.request']]"
                contentType="text/plain" method="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method']]" doc:name="HTTP" />

Comment: The payload of the request will automatically get propagated across endpoints. If you want to propagate all inbound properties across the outbound endpoint you could use: <copy-properties propertyName="*"/>  or <copy-properties propertyName="http*"/> or manually copy the properties you want. If you need to construct the URL dynamically, then the scheme: i.e "http://" must be static in the "address" field, it can't be dynamic. For example:  <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://#[payload..getHost()...]" /> or  <http:endpoint host="#[payload.getHost()]" path="#[payload.getPath()..." />

Comment: I used <copy-properties propertyName="http.method" doc:name="Copy HTTP METHOD" />, It's OK. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: I used <copy-properties propertyName="http.method" doc:name="Copy HTTP METHOD" />, It's OK for get and post, but PUT and DELTE got error: The HTTP method or content type is unsupported!

Comment: That's another issue. The http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer you are using only supports GET and POST. See here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference. You can wrap that transformer in a a choice router i.e <choice when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] == 'POST'...]">

Comment: I found the http:rest-service-component, but It does not support PUT method? why?

Comment: The transformer you are using is your problem:  http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer. I would close this and open a new question with the new issue.

Comment: I did not use that transformer, is it default? Thanks, Ryan.

Comment: It's on line 6 of the example in your original question post.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a http:outbound to the actual rest service in your otherwise block.

Try using the following.

```
<otherwise>
          <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/"></http:outbound-endpoint>
</otherwise>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above?