# Why mule's http:rest-service-component does not support PUT method?

Tags: mule

I want to call rest service in flow, at first, I use http:outbound-endpoint as following:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            address="http://localhost:7081#[message.inboundProperties['http.request']]" doc:name="Call Lower REST" method="PUT">
```

EDIT:

Request:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/ae2/app/add?nonce=23ddd&name=app1&timestamp=123332&user=foo HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

It throws an exception:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.Exception: The HTTP method or content type is unsupported!
  at org.mule.transport.http.transformers.HttpRequestBodyToParamMap.transformMessage(HttpRequestBodyToParamMap.java:56)
  at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:145)
  at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:93)
```

Then I  read some document, and I found the http:rest-service-component, it can call the backend rest service, but it does not support PUT method, the document says, and I tried.

So, Why this component does not support PUT? Or is there anthoer component can be used?

Comment: What content type is the body of the PUT request you are making? The error is thrown from the HttpRequestBodyToParamMap transformer you are using which does not support PUT or DELETE. Is your PUT request multipart form data?

Comment: I don't known, I just use soapUI send PUT method. See my EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not being thrown from the outbound endpoint. Somewhere in your flow you are using:

```
<http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map" />
```

In you config here: [mule's http-proxy cannot be used in flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141517/mules-http-proxy-cannot-be-used-in-flow) - you are using it a few lines down after your first logger.

This transformer will return the message properties as a hash map of name-value pairs. This transformer handles GET and POST with application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type. This transformer does not support PUT or DELETE.

You are PUTing XML so theres no need to use this transformer.

If you still need it for POST, then you can wrap this transformer in a choice so it only gets used for GET and POST. For example:

```
  <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] == 'POST']">
      <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map" />
      ...
    </when>
  </choice>
```

Otherwise remove it.

Comment: You are right, I removed http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer, It's OK now! Thanks Ryan.